# Формулировка «сообщения низкого качества»

Tags: обсуждение, качество-вопроса

Представляется мне неудачной: неточно отражающей суть сообщений, которые попадают в эту очередь, и отпугивающей новичков от участия в Stack Overflow на русском.

1. В бытность начинающим пользователем, не имеющим возможности оставлять комментарии к чужим вопросам/ответам, я задал уточняющий вопрос, отправив своё сообщение как ответ. Вскоре к моему сообщению проставили шаблонный комментарий, в котором, в частности, указывалось, что оно попало в «сообщения низкого качества».
2. Недавно увидел, что в «сообщения низкого качества» попал ответ-ссылка от нового участника, причём, по всей видимости, правильный. Тот ответ уже удалили, было что-то вроде «Я тоже долго мучилась с кодировками, нашла ответ здесь (следует ссылка)».

Полагаю, в обоих случаях ответы хоть и не соответствовали правилам русскоязычного Stack Overflow, но были не такого уж и «низкого качества», и предлагаю заменить формулировку на более нейтральную и конкретную вроде «сообщения, не соответствующие правилам».

Answer (score 4):

Не соответствует правилам - это и оскорбительное, и вопрос не по теме, и реклама, и предполагает субъективные ответы. А низкого качества - гораздо меньшее подмножество вопросов и ответов.

В эту очередь попадают сообщения после тревог следующих типов:

> **необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством**
>    У данного вопроса серьезные проблемы с форматированием или содержанием. Поскольку маловероятно, что его удастся улучшить с помощью правок, этот вопрос нужно удалить.
>
> **не является ответом**
>   Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.
>
> **необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством**
>   Ответ имеет серьезные проблемы с форматированием или контентом. Ответ вряд ли удастся исправить с помощью правок, поэтому его необходимо удалить.
>
> **слишком короткое**
>   (это автоматическая тревога от Духа Сообщества)

- Вопросы, которые вообще не содержат вопроса;
- Ответы, которые вообще не являются попыткой ответить («у меня та же проблема» или «спасибо, мне помогло»);
- Совсем что-то непонятное.

Да, эти вопросы и ответы — низкого качества. Зачем приукрашивать и вводить ненужную толерантность?

Comment: > Зачем приукрашивать и вводить ненужную толерантность? — Выразил в первом предложении поста: *Представляется мне неудачной: неточно отражающей суть сообщений, которые попадают в эту очередь, и отпугивающей новичков от участия в Stack Overflow на русском.* // > Да, эти вопросы и ответы — низкого качества. — Полагаю, что сообщения, соответствующие пп. 2, 4, а именно уточняющие комментарии, правки и слишком короткие ответы, а также не упомянутые Вами ответы-ссылки не всегда «низкого качества». Что моя формулировка также неудачная — согласен. Спасибо.